# Local Jar dependency in gradle: how to import into code

Tags: java, gradle, import, jar, dependencies

I'm building a gradle project with a testone.jar dependency

testone.jar is a working .jar with a class Brew that prints stuff.

I want to call testone.Brew from Main.java.

```
" import testone.Brew; " gives me a compile error
```

">gradle build" works, ">gradle dependencies" show:

```
implementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
\--- unspecified (n)
```

Folder Structure:

```
GradleTest/

----build/

--------libs/

------------GradleTest.jar

----libs/

--------testone.jar

----src/

--------test/

--------main/net/alexhublon/gradletest/

--------------------------------------Main.java
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs';
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation files("libs/testone.jar")
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir 'src/main'
    test.java.srcDir 'src/test'
}

jar {
    manifest.attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.alexhublon.gradletest.Main'
}
```

Here is the code for Main.java:

```
package net.alexhublon.gradletest;

import java.util.Arrays;
//import libs/testone.jar???
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Finished");
                //testone.Brew brew = new Brew()???
    }
}
```

I would like to import and use the functions from testone.jar

Edit:
If you compile the .jar file with the class, it works. I believe the problem is with Gradle

Answer (score 0):

Simply import it as you did with `Arrays`:

```
package net.alexhublon.gradletest;

import java.util.Arrays;
import testone.Brew;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Finished");
        Brew brew = new Brew()
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: error: package testone does not exist
import testone.Brew;